# Realm Object Server error

Tags: swift, cocoa, realm, realm-mobile-platform

**Pre-Condition**: before changing to https everything worked smoothly.

After successfully login to Realm Server.

When I try to create a new entity I keep getting the following error :

    `Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::read_http_message_line()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Websocket: http_line = HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::read_http_message_line()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Websocket: http_line = upgrade: websocket
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::read_http_message_line()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Websocket: http_line = connection: Upgrade
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::read_http_message_line()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Websocket: http_line = sec-websocket-accept: ZoPQVRYX/stlDEtEXDfNdZrkbg8=
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::read_http_message_line()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Websocket: http_line = sec-websocket-protocol: io.realm.protocol
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::read_http_message_line()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Websocket: http_line = 
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::handle_http_response_received()
    Sync: Connection[1]: Sending: CLIENT(protocol_version=15, client_info_size=2)
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::frame_reader_loop()
    Sync: Connection[1]: stage_init
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket: frame_reader.read_size = 2
    Sync: Connection[1]: Session[1]: Sending: BIND(server_path='/e50e728d9ed228cac9dfaf9da5e7a265/userRealm', signed_user_token_size=597, need_file_ident_pair=1)
    Sync: Connection[1]: handle_write_output_buffer
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::frame_reader_loop()
    Sync: Connection[1]: stage_header_beginning
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket: frame_reader.read_size = 56
    Sync: Connection[1]: WebSocket::frame_reader_loop()
    Sync: Connection[1]: stage_payload
    Sync: Connection[1]: websocket message received: error 203 39 0 1
    Bad user authentication (BIND, REFRESH)
    Sync: Connection[1]: message_type = error
    Sync: Connection[1]: Received: ERROR(error_code=203, message_size=39, try_again=0, session_ident=1)
    Sync: Connection[1]: Connection closed due to error reported by server: Bad user authentication (BIND, REFRESH) (203)
    Sync: Connection[1]: Reconnecting in 19655 milliseconds
    Sync: Closing Realm file: /Users/pippo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A04D4CE0-E711-440A-95F3-019360DC9333/data/Containers/Data/Application/C2ECFB54-F28E-472F-A0FB-024039FB1E1A/Documents/realm-object-server/e50e728d9ed228cac9dfaf9da5e7a265/realm%3A%2F%2Fpippo.it%3A9080%2F%7E%2FuserRealm
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot set a sync configuration which has an errored-out user.'`

After disabling the https it still does not work.
Is it related??

Can anyone elaborate on the error?

Thank you

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? If yes, please try to provide more context and details. Describe how anyone would go about reproducing this issue you have.

Comment: a re-install of Realm Server fixed the issue